# ¿Cómo esconder el "#" hash de una url usando vanilla js en una OnePage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una pagina que usa un `<a href="#portafolio">` para desplazar hacia una ancla especifica como esta `<a name="portafolio">&nbsp;</a>`.

Cuando doy click a un link `<a href="#portafolio">` se crea una dirección como esta `http://myportafolio.com/#portafolio`

Cómo hacer usando vanilla.js o cualquier otro método sugerido para ocultar el hash de la url y que no se genere historial; ya que, al dar click a un link del menu se genera un historial, que al dar **hacia atrás** en la barra de busqueda del navegador recorre todas los links visitados hasta regresar al inicio y al refrescar el navegador se queda en el último link visitado.

Cómo transforma esto: `http://myportafolio.com/#portafolio` en esto: `http://myportafolio.com/` sin generar historial cuando visito una ancla dentro la misma pagina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo sin utilizar una etiqueta **button** y hacerlo vía una etiqueta **a** de una vez manteniendo el comportamiento de un ancla y controlando de forma centralizada las eliminaciones de hash, puedes simplemente hacerlo en window.onhashchange:

```js
  window.onhashchange = function () {
    window.history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname)
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#hash" id="remove">Simular</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <a id="hash"></a>
  <h1>That's ancla</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Este enfoque es el recomendado, siempre y cuando quieras eliminar el hash de todas las anclas, y en caso de querer filtrar las eliminaciones puedes hacerlo desde aquí.

Si en en cambio quieres tener un control más descentralizado sobre cada etiqueta , puedes crear una tarea asíncrona al ejecutar el comportamiento del ancla para eliminar el hash:

```js
function removeHash() {
  // Ejecutar en una tarea asíncrona para eliminar el hash
  setTimeout(function() {
   window.history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname)
  }, 500)
}

const removeLnk = document.getElementById('remove')
removeLnk.onclick = removeHash
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#hash" id="remove">Simular</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <a id="hash"></a>
  <h1>That's ancla</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Con esta última solución el manejo de los eventos sobre cada ancla es independiente de las otras.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauro, funcionó perfecto. Me faltaba el callback

Answer (score 2):

Puedes referirte a este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r/5298684#5298684

Pero básicamente sería alterando la historia del navegador:

`window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);`

```js
function removeHash() { 
    window.history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname)
    btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == '#')     
}

const btn = document.getElementById('remove')

btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == '#')
btn.onclick = removeHash

window.onhashchange = function () { 
    btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == '#')     
}
```

```html
<button id="remove" disabled>Quitar #</button> <a href="#hash">Simular</a>
```

Si no quieres preservar la historia puedes utilizar en lugar de pushBack:

`window.history.replaceState(null, null, ' ')`

Puedes averiguar más sobre este hilo en este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r

Comment: Gracias Mauro por tu respuesta, probé el código y realmente funciona, pero no he podido implementarlo con el ancla `<a>` para que se quite automáticamente el `#hash` Aquí el código https://jsfiddle.net/JuanDSi/dkeos6xt/13/

Comment: Te lo contesto en otra respuesta que extienda a la que te he dado aquí para que quedé la referencia y la comunidad pueda colaborar en aportar más información de creerlo necesario. El código de las dos soluciones puedes encontrarlo también aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/mastepanoski/mn2v4swj/ , https://jsfiddle.net/mastepanoski/y8x7p3m9/, para las dos formas.